# Can we delete a list of Ids from database?

Tags: sql, reactjs, sql-delete

Can we delete a list of Ids (int[]) in database from react? I have below and it doesn't work ... error message is: SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'M', "Microsoft."... is not valid JSON

==================================================

```
  deleteIdList() 
    {    
       const idList = this.state.selectedEmployeeIdList; 
  
       if (window.confirm('Are you sure list of Employee(s)?'))
       {
            fetch(variables.API_URL + 'employee/' + idList, {
                method : 'DELETE',
                headers :  {
                    'Accept' : 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
                } 
            })
            .then(res=>res.json())
            .then((result) => {
                alert('deleted')
                alert(result);
                this.refreshList();
            },(error)=>{
                alert('Cannot Delete Selected Employee(s)!!!!! ' + error);
            })
        } 
    }
```

In VS 2019:

```
 [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public JsonResult Delete(int[] id)
        {
            string query = @"DELETE FROM DBO.EMPLOYEE WHERE EMPLOYEEID in @EMPLOYEEIDs";

            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            SqlDataReader dr;
            string sqlDataSource = _configuration.GetConnectionString("EmployeeAppConn");

            using (SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(sqlDataSource))
            {
                myConn.Open();

                using (SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(query, myConn))
                {
                    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EMPLOYEEIDs", id);

                    dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
                    table.Load(dr);
                    dr.Close();
                    myConn.Close();
                }
            }

            return new JsonResult("Employee #" + id.ToString() + " deleted!");
        }
```

Comment: please tag with database platform

Comment: It seems like you are server response for the delete api is not returing valid json..  .then(res=>res.json())    instead try this.    .then(res=>res)